# How to copy NSMutableDictionary values into the another NSMutableDictionary in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsmutabledictionary

I want to copy a NSMUtableDictionary values into the another NSMutableDictioary. How can i do that?

Here my code is,

```
 PersonClass.h file:

 NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *tempDictionary;

 PersonClass.m
 @synthesize tempDictionary; 

 tempDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

-(PersonClass *) initWithPerson:(NSMutableDictionary *) feedDictionary
{
     // get all the values in feedDictionary.

     //Now i want copy of the details from feedDictionary into the tempDictionary

           tempDictionary = feedDictionary; // Doesn't copy.
}
```

I want to access the tempDictionary values to the person class. SO how can i copy from feedDictionary to the tempDictionary. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about this?

```
tempDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:feedDictionary];
```

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

```
[feedDictionary mutableCopy];
```

This will copy all entries in the dictionary, but it will not copy custom objects unless you implement the NSCopying protocol.

Answer (score -1):

a very simple way to get a deep mutable copy of a dictionary is to use JSON.
It also gives the chance to have a look at values in dictionaries

```
NSString *dictStr = [sourceMutableDict JSONRepresentation];
// NSLog(@"copied data dict: %@", dictStr);
copyMutableDict = [[dictStr JSONValue] retain];
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way to save.
Suppose you have copy mutable dictionary named "dictA" into new mutable dictionary named "dictB". but make sure dictB have alloc and init.

```
[dictB setDictionary:dictA];
```

Hope this helpful.