# ios adding array of dictionaries to another array of dictionaries

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to add the dictionaries I have in one array to another array with dictionaries so I can have one array with the dictionaries of both arrays.

I have tried this:

```
[arrayOne arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:arrayTwo];
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
-[__NSDictionaryM arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75ba1a0
```

Comment: arrayOne is not an NSArray instance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying the contents of an NSMutableDictionary into another NSMutableDictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600386/copying-the-contents-of-an-nsmutabledictionary-into-another-nsmutabledictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (NSArray *)arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)otherArray;
```

This function returns NSArray not NSDictionary, I guess in your code arrayOne is NSDictionary not NSArray right?

In Xcode source check warning shown for below line

```
[arrayOne arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:arrayTwo];
```

To copy dictionary refer this: [Copying the contents of an NSMutableDictionary into another NSMutableDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600386/copying-the-contents-of-an-nsmutabledictionary-into-another-nsmutabledictionary)